# Sublime Text 3 rectangular tabs (title bar)

Tags: sublime-text-3, sublime-text

[image: http://devthemez.com/uploads/5356592432586.png]

This sublime theme looks so great. The thing is that only the color of text is changed when I install it.

What should I do to get that rectangular tabs (title bar) in my sublime? It's operating system specific design or sublime text ? I'm using windows 8.1 . If there's a theme for windows that make that tabs rectangular let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is the theme within Sublime Text 3. The name of the theme is [Afterglow](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Theme%20-%20Afterglow).

To install it do the following steps:

- Open Preferences > Package Control > Install package
- Search for "Afterglow" and install it
- Open Preferences > Settings - User
- Add these lines:

> ```
> "theme": "Afterglow.sublime-theme",
> "color_scheme": "Packages/Theme - Afterglow/Afterglow.tmTheme",
> ```

- Save files and restart Sublime Text 3

You might also want to see

- [35 Cool Sublime Text themes](http://designbeep.com/2014/06/10/35-cool-sublime-text-themes/)

Comment: Thanks. The problem was that in my User Settings file I was having only `"color_scheme": "Packages/Theme - Afterglow/Afterglow.tmTheme"` not both of them.

Answer (score 1):

If you want, you can try the theme I created from Spacegray. I called it [Spacegray Midnight](https://github.com/phackwer/spacegray), all black.

You can see it in action here:

[image]